# Jquery Ajax request repeating infinitely in Safari on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, nginx, catalyst

I've encountered a vexing little problem with Jquery Ajax in Safari. I'm using Ajax to load/refresh static svg content on a section of the app I'm developing. I'm making an initial Ajax call when the page is first loaded, then updating the map with subsequent calls to the same function based on menu clicks on the page. Code for all are below but first, a description of the problem.

All this works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but in Safari, the page, **on initial load and page-reload only**, is generating an infinite loop of requests to the server. Strangely, if I stop the page loading, subsequent updates to the map from the menus work just fine. It seems that the Ajax call is returning an error status -- the second "alert" in the code below is being triggered but the dialog is empty, so no additional information on what the problem might be.

nginx access log lines are included below, along with all applicable code snippets. There are no errors in the /var/log/nginx/error.log, even if I start fcgi with CATALYST_DEBUG=1 set.

Really hoping someone can give me some insight here because I'm at a loss!

**UPDATE** -- I'm running into the same problem in testing with the Catalyst development server, so this is not an issue with nginx or fcgi. More likely something with the JS. I've also tried disabling the code bits represented as comments in the blocks here and they have no effect on the behavior, as expected.

1) Shared function for serving up an SVG image -- note that I'm just getting the location of the static content from Catalyst here and leaving serving the actual content to nginx...

```
function loadSvgMap(mapId) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url:      "[% c.uri_for('/maps/update_map/') %]" + mapId,
        success:  function(result) {
            if(result.isOk == false) {
                alert(result.message);
            } else {
                $("#som_map").load(result);
            }
        },
        error:    function(result, status, errorThrown) {
            alert(errorThrown);
        },
        async:    true,
        dataType: 'text'
    });
}
```

2) Initial call on page load

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var mapId = [% map_id %];
    loadSvgMap(mapId);

/* other stuff to set the url and browser history*/
})
```

3) Subsequent updates based on menu clicks

```
$(document).on("click",".map_select", function(e){
    loadSvgMap(this.name);

    /* other stuff to update browser history and location */ 
})
```

4) Catalyst handler for page load:

```
sub map :Path :Local :Args(1) {
    my ( $self, $c , $map_id ) = @_;

    $c->stash(menus => [$c->model('DB::Menus')->build_menu($c->model('DB::Map'), $c->model('DB::MapsMenus'))]);
    $c->stash(map_id => $map_id);                             
    $c->stash(neuron => '');                                 
    $c->stash(template => 'maps/som_main.tt2');

    my %params = %{$c->request->params};
    if (exists($params{neuron})) {
        return $c->res->redirect( $c->uri_for('neuron', $map_id, $params{neuron}));
    }
}
```

5) Catalyst handler for map updates

```
sub update_map :Path :Local :Args(1) {
    my ( $self, $c, $map_id ) = @_;

    my $fields = $c->model('DB::Map')->find($map_id);
    my $map_file = $fields->get_column('map_file');                               
    my $returnUrl = $c->uri_for('/static/svg', $map_file);

    $c->res->content_type("text/plain");
    $c->res->body($returnUrl);
}
```

6) nginx access log lines

```
10.0.2.2 - - [20/Nov/2015:16:07:35 +0000] "GET /maps/map/305 HTTP/1.1" 200 3335 "http://poppy.med.umich.edu:5000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/601.1.56 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Safari/601.1.56"
10.0.2.2 - - [20/Nov/2015:16:07:35 +0000] "GET /maps/get_map_info/305 HTTP/1.1" 499 0 "http://poppy.med.umich.edu:5000/maps/map/305" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/601.1.56 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Safari/601.1.56"
10.0.2.2 - - [20/Nov/2015:16:07:35 +0000] "GET /maps/update_map/305 HTTP/1.1" 200 51 "http://poppy.med.umich.edu:5000/maps/map/305" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/601.1.56 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.0 Safari/601.1.56"
```

Note that the "499" status for the one request indicates a client-side hangup. This does not always affect the same request -- seems to just be whichever is currently running when the error is triggered in Safari. Once the initial "alert" is dismissed (if I check "Don't show more alerts..."), those three lines will repeat infinitely until I stop page loading. After that, I can use a menu to choose a map and everything works fine.

For comparison, here is the log output for a request from firefox...

```
10.21.136.38 - - [20/Nov/2015:16:30:03 +0000] "GET /maps/map/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 3318 "http://10.21.136.66/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0"
10.21.136.38 - - [20/Nov/2015:16:30:04 +0000] "GET /maps/update_map/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 48 "http://10.21.136.66/maps/map/1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0"
10.21.136.38 - - [20/Nov/2015:16:30:04 +0000] "GET /maps/get_map_info/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 394 "http://10.21.136.66/maps/map/1" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple more hours of experimentation, I determined this problem is actually entirely unrelated to Jquery Ajax. Rather, it related to my manipulations to the browser history. Specifically, I am listening for window.popstate events to trigger handling of the browser nav buttons:

```
$(window).on('popstate', function(event) {
    var state = event.originalEvent.state;
    if (state) {
        window.location.assign(state.url);
    } else {
        window.location.assign(document.location.href);
    }
});
```

This was the problem, since Safari fires a popstate event whenever the browser history changes, whether it's from a nav action or page (re)load. (Something they fixed in Chrome some time ago -- come on, Safari! Follow standards much?) To fix the problem, I applied the following hack:

1) When the state is created for the browser history entry, include a tag to indicate that we created that entry:

```
var state = { url: newUrl, title: newTitle, loadTag: true };
window.history.pushState(state, "", newUrl); // or replaceState, for first page load
```

2) Within the popstate listener, check for our tag and do nothing unless we find it:

```
$(window).on('popstate', function(event) {
    var state = event.originalEvent.state;
    if (!state.loadTag) return;

    ...
```

Problem solved... just wish I'd discovered the real problem before spending hours trying to fix the wrong one!

Comment: Please mark your answer as the solution to your question